# Can you get the system answer call button in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

When you get a call on iPhone a system alert it is shown. There is a nice answer call button, can I use somehow this button on my app or i have to design it by myself?

I suppose this are system resources and could be available in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not available for public use in the iOS SDK as of iOS 5

Comment: i could not find any other answer or reference so i'm going to trust you and stop searching :)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to fetch tat button from an iPhone or its simulator but why don't you customize your own button using this site http://dabuttonfactory.com/ ? It helped me sometimes when I needed buttons for my apps as well.

Comment: Because is the only button I need and if I create it by myself I have to localize the button. If I get the system one is no need for that.